# split string into array object in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, object

I have a string like this: "abc@gmail.com;ABC,xyz@gmail.com;XYZ" and I want to convert into array boject. How can I do that?
Below is sample

```
$noactivity_noassignedto = "abc@gmail.com;ABC,xyz@gmail.com;XYZ";
$assignedto = explode(';', $noactivity_noassignedto);
$assignedto = array((object) array("Email" => $assignedto[0], "Name" => $assignedto[1]));
$fromadd = 'some@abc.com';
$fromname = 'somename';
/*sending mail here*/
$this->init()->setsubject($sub)->addto($assignedto)->setfrom($fromadd, $fromname)->send();
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: unable split the string $noactivity_noassignedto based in ;(character) need to pass the variable to addto()

Comment: What's the desired content of the $assignedto?

Comment: need to send email for both emails

Comment: I understand, but we don't know the $this->addto() method - you have to post it's code if you don't know how exactly the object code should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$noactivity_noassignedto = "abc@gmail.com;ABC,xyz@gmail.com;XYZ";
$assignedto = explode(',', $noactivity_noassignedto);

foreach ($assignedto as $recipient) {
    $tmp = explode(';', $recipient);
    $recipients[] = (object)array("Email" => $tmp[0], "Name" => $tmp[1]);
}
$recipients = (object)$recipients;
```

Comment: can i directly pass to $this->init()->setsubject($sub)->addto($recipients)->setfrom($fromadd, $fromname)->send(); is this correct method

Comment: Yes, but check if the $recipient has the structure which your `addto()` method needs. I don't see into your method, just made what you asked for

Comment: `$recipients = (object)$recipients;` line is unnecessary, its already in correct format without that line

Comment: @RiggsFolly I understand, but what if OP's `addto()` method checks the type? He demands an object, or "into array boject" could mean "array of objects?" :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$noactivity_noassignedto = "abc@gmail.com;ABC,xyz@gmail.com;XYZ";
$elements = explode(',', $noactivity_noassignedto);
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $dummy = explode(';', $element);
    $assignedto[] = (object)array("Email" => $dummy[0], "Name" => $dummy[1]);
}
```

Comment: Your not looking very closely @Anant

Comment: This is an array of arrays not an array of objects with names properties

Comment: @RiggsFolly I assume Anant said that because my answer was the first to perform the first explode correctly, not ';' but ',' for delimiter.

Comment: Thats better, DV removed

Answer (score 0):

This will generate the array of objects that you want

```
$noactivity_noassignedto = "abc@gmail.com;ABC,xyz@gmail.com;XYZ";
$assignedto = explode(',', $noactivity_noassignedto);

foreach($assignedto as $item) {
    list($email, $name) = explode(';', $item);
    $addresses[] = (object)['Name'=>$name, 'Email'=>$email];
}

print_r($addresses);
```

Result: a `print_r($addresses);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Name] => ABC
            [Email] => abc@gmail.com
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Name] => XYZ
            [Email] => xyz@gmail.com
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two explode

```
   $noactivity_noassignedto = "abc@gmail.com;ABC,xyz@gmail.com;XYZ";
   $assignedAll = explode(',', $noactivity_noassignedto);

   // here you can put loop to send all, for now just first
   $assignedto = explode(';', $assignedAll[0]);
   $assignedto = array((object) array("Email" => $assignedto[0], "Name" => $assignedto[1]));
```

Comment: But only one `name-emails` set not 2

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right path. `explode` is what you are looking for to split a string into an array.
Given

```
$str = "abc@gmail.com;ABC";
$arr = explode($str, ';');
```

$arr will be `array('abc@gmail.com', 'ABC');`.

I think your problem is you want to invoke this multiple times. To do this:

```
$str = "abc@gmail.com;ABC,def@gmail.com;DEF";
$people = explode($str, ',');
foreach ($people as $person) {
    $assigned_to = explode($person, ';');
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: i can directly add the $this->init()->setsubject($sub)->addto($assignedto)->setfrom($fromadd, $fromname)->send(); line into forloop after your commets